# How to embed an annotated and compilable source/example in Doxygen?

Tags: documentation, doxygen

I want to have a compilable example in my software, which is annotated so it can be included in the doxygen `.dox`. The critical part here is that I want the annotations to be part of the source code (which is supposed to be the whole point of doxygen but it seems to lack this simple feature)

So, is it possible to include it in such a way that it looks like a mixture of text and code, much like the `\dontinclude` example [here](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/examples/include/html/example.html)?

`\snippet`-s don't seem to be useful as they would require the annotations to be separated from the code. The same goes for `\dontinclude`.

The only idea I have right now is to write a script to be used as a pre-doxygen step, which parses the example sources and generates `.dox` files with text and `\code` blocks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well... I wrote the script I mentioned above.

I'm posting it here in case it could be of help for somebody with the same problem: https://gist.github.com/iboB/925542e1ed5afee2b0083ff4fa970462

There's an example usage in the gist